# Can we set Minimum time for a telerik rad time picker in code behind

Tags: vb.net, telerik

I am having a telerik RadTimePicker can we set the mimimum Start Time and End Time from code behind.Right now I am using this to display which is from 6 AM to 9PM.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the RadTimePicker1.TimeView.StartTime and RadTimePicker1.TimeView.EndTime properties of the control:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        RadTimePicker1.TimeView.StartTime = New TimeSpan(8, 0, 0)
        RadTimePicker1.TimeView.EndTime = New TimeSpan(18, 0, 0)
        RadTimePicker1.TimeView.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
        RadTimePicker1.TimeView.HeaderText = ""
        RadTimePicker1.TimeView.Columns = 4
    End If
End Sub
```